How to efficiently manage multiple WebClient configurations in a Spring Boot microservices architecture?
I'm working on a microservices project using Spring Boot and have multiple services that need to communicate with each other. Currently, I have the following services:

Employee Service
Department Service
Project Service.

In the Employee Service, I need to call endpoints from both the Department Service and the Project Service using WebClient. Initially, I created individual WebClient beans for each service, like this:
@Autowired
private LoadBalancedExchangeFilterFunction filterFunction;

@Bean
public WebClient departmentWebClient() {
    return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://department-service")
            .filter(filterFunction)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public DepartmentClient departmentClient() {
    HttpServiceProxyFactory httpServiceProxyFactory
            = HttpServiceProxyFactory
            .builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(departmentWebClient()))
            .build();
    return httpServiceProxyFactory.createClient(DepartmentClient.class);
}

@Bean
public WebClient projectWebClient() {
    return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://project-service")
            .filter(filterFunction)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public TaskClient taskClient() {
    HttpServiceProxyFactory httpServiceProxyFactory
            = HttpServiceProxyFactory
            .builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(projectWebClient()))
            .build();
    return httpServiceProxyFactory.createClient(TaskClient.class);
}


While this works, it seems inefficient and cumbersome as the number of services increases. I'm looking for a better and more flexible approach if possible.
Could someone guide me on the best approach to achieve this, possibly with code examples?

Why do you think it's inefficient? Definitely number of services may increase but it would be managable. If not then we should rethink about design. Why one service is communicating with enormous number of other services and whether we can cut down the dependency or not?

If you dont want many instances of a webClient, you could instead make a bean of WebClient.Builder and inject that on your services. Then, each service, could  construct their URL

maybe you should use a declarative rest client like open feign you will have an interface representing each microservice with all the endpoints it has like this example:
@FeignClient(value = "jplaceholder", url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
public interface JSONPlaceHolderClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/posts")
    List<Post> getPosts();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/posts/{postId}", produces = "application/json")
    Post getPostById(@PathVariable("postId") Long postId);
}

and you will inject this interface into your service and just call the methods from the interface you injected. each method in this interface will represent and endpoint you have in your other microservice. you can have a feign client for each microservice. This should be easier and more maintainable than using rest template or web client.

Don't think this fits into the question. Feign client is blocking while the WebClient is not

Unfortunately, Spring Declarative HTTP Interfaces are nowhere near Feign Client's usability in terms of features and usage experience. All I can recommend to you is to shorten your declarations and reuse code for building WebClient/HttpServiceProxyFactory when possible.
It looks like you don't need two WebClient beans in the example you shared. So, you can move the logic of building a proxy factory to a single method.
@Autowired
private LoadBalancedExchangeFilterFunction filterFunction;

@Bean
public DepartmentClient departmentClient() {
    return buildFactory("http://department-service").createClient(DepartmentClient.class);
}

@Bean
public TaskClient taskClient() {
    return buildFactory("http://project-service").createClient(TaskClient.class);
}

private HttpServiceProxyFactory buildFactory(String baseUrl) {
    final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .filter(filterFunction)
            .build();
    return HttpServiceProxyFactory.builderFor(WebClientAdapter.create(webClient)).build();
}

ofc, you can improve the code by creating constants, adding bean injections, etc. but the idea is to keep common logic in one place.
